# Installation with MS SQL Server on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, sql-server

I am stuggling to install MS SQL Server on Windows 7. I'm following instruction to re install SP3 and then install MS SQL Server and then install SP3 again. However when I try to install SP3 I get the message telling me "This machine does not have a product that matches this installation".

Do you have any pointers you could give me?

Comment: which version of sql server are you trying to install?

Comment: So is letter sent to Jack from David? Also, the instructions don't make much sense... reinstall SP3, then SQL, then install SP3 again? If you could clarify it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to install the SQL Service Pack before installing the base product. That's true for any piece of software.

Perhaps they meant for you to apply all the current Windows Service Packs first. Then, install SQL Server, and finally SQL Service Packs.

That is the correct order.